# Vite/Vue & Ionic do not recognize my SCSS files

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, sass, vite

Vite is not recognizing my SCSS files and I do not understand why.

I am unable to use my SCSS, such as `$color-primary`, variables inside my components' `<style>` tag

I have already tried adding:

```
// vite.config.ts

css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
            additionalData: `@use "./src/scss/global.scss" as *;`,
        },
    },
},
```

Note: `@import` doesn't work either, nor does removing `as *`.

Importing my SCSS files directly into my `main.ts` doesn't work either:

```
// src/main.ts

import "./scss/_global.scss";
```

I have already run

`npm install -D sass`

My components do have

`<style scoped lang="scss">`

My stack:

```
dependencies: {
    "@ionic/vue": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^7.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
},
devDependencies: {
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vitest": "^0.32.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.24"
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Plugin: vite:css
File: C:\***\src\scss\_global.scss:7:9
Error: Undefined variable.
```

Comment: What are the contents of `_global.scss`?